# how can I localize mvc routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am currently working with localizing my MVC4 web application and have run in to an issue. My site is in four languages, English, French, Russian and Polish. I set up the sites culture based upon what the user selects. This is not tracked in the url.

I want my urls to be SEO friendly. So I need them to be localized. The tricky part though is that fact I routes set up for my controllers in English. For example

/product/product-name is mapped to the product controller and the get action
/customer/details is mapped to the customer controller and the details action

How can I localize the routes to different languages/cultures? So when I create an action link it maps to correct controller/action, generating the localized url?

I found [this](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx) solution and it is very elegant but the issue I have is that it does not work as well for dynamic url's, as there is a need for explicit mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know the right answer for that question and it's really very interesting how it possible to do that with standard MVC routing.

But if you do not find proper way to implement that with standard options you could implementing that by hands with the helps of [front controler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

You create the class which will be main point of availability inside your app. And inside that method you could implement redirecting logic which will redirect you to the proper controller/action.